# How to finde a node name that publish a known topic?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the name of a topic but how can I find the node that is publishing that topic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230636/how-to-finde-a-node-name-that-publish-a-known-topic?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 rostopic info /topicname
```

prints the publishers and subscribers of this topic.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2